# Communication between two Silverlight Applications, after opening the second one from the first one

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, silverlight

I have two Silverlight applications. Let's say names of the applications are like that:
Site1 and Site2.

I am opening Site 2 from Site1 like that:

```
System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri("http://localhost/Site2"), "_blank").;
```

And I dont want users can open the second web site with just putting URI into the address bar.
The second web site must only be opened through the first Web Site.

I have read [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/236861/Communicating-Between-Two-Local-Silverlight-Applic) to communicate between two Silverlight web applications.
After reading this I have tried to send message to the second Application directly after opening it like that:

```
    System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri("http://localhost/Site2"), "_blank");
   _messageSender.SendAsync("Hi, I am first Web Application");
```

But it is not working. Because it is trying to send message before the second web site opens completely.

So, the real problem is that :
I want to know that, is the second website opened through the first website or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used IsolatedStorage **SiteSettings** for this purpose. I am setting StatusForSecondWebApplication key's value to 1 after opening the second web application. And in the second web applicationI am checking the value of this key. If it is set to 1, the web application opens and I am setting the value of this key to 0. That's all.